# Word for a police man getting money from someone forcefully

Tags: word-choice

My wife bought a puppet from a roadside salesman. She noticed a policeman taking away the money from the salesman forcefully.

Is there an appropriate word for the policeman's behaviour? Bribe is not the word because the salesman was not trying to bribe here. Words like rob, steal, loot come to my mind. But I want to know if there is a better fit.

Update: The way the incident was perceived by my wife (and the original intention in my question) is that the policeman did this for his personal gain and was not doing it as a part of his duty.

Comment: Whether there is a _better fit_ than **steal** will depend on the circumstances. It is possible (although you make it sound unlikely)  that there was a legal justification for the action. If not, then **steal** is absolutely correct.

Comment: Was the policeman doing this for personal gain or legitimately as part of his job? I'd argue `confiscate` wouldn't fit the former as well.

Comment: @Fortiter: I may be in the minority, but to me "steal" still implies stealth.

Comment: Depending on the country, or if you asked the businessman what just happened, it might just be, **Business as usual.**

Comment: @Beta: According to the *Online Etymology Dictionary*, [*steal*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=steal) and [*stealth*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stealth) originally related to theft (as *steal* still does), with the modern sense of *stealth* (and associated sense of *steal*) developing only around 1300. So while it's possible that *steal* now implies stealth to you, that would be a recent development: it can't "still" imply stealth to you.

Comment: @Beta "steal" doesn't imply stealth to me:  "He just stole my purse!"

Comment: is this the appropriate place to add regional/ethnic jokes?  hehe

Comment: @LeonardChallis The assumption here is the policeman was doing this for personal gain. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @LeonardChallis, Do you think the policeman was taking advantage of his position as a policeman to effect the robbery?  I think if he did, then *confiscate* still applies.

Comment: @Jim I think it fits still but is more ambiguous than extortion

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The appropriate word to use in this context (abuse of authority) is [extortion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extortion?s=ts).

Strictly applied ***confiscate*** refers specifically to appropriation for the public treasury (*fisc*).

Comment: Strictly according to whom? That's it's origin, but not its only meaning.

Comment: @Matt: [Spot on](http://www.wordnik.com/words/confiscate).

Comment: **confiscate** verb
to seize or take (something) away, usually as a penalty. _The teacher confiscated the boy's comic which he was reading in class._
Kernerman English Multilingual Dictionary © 2006-2013 K Dictionaries Ltd. Sounds like the teacher was being strict here, but I bet he didn't mail the _Beano_ to the Treasury. Seriously, I'm pretty sure that the most common usage (and thus the one most sensibly deduced, except when a specialist register is obviously being used) is the one instanced here. The entries in most dictionaries don't seem to reflect this.

Comment: @Edwin: First definition of *confiscate* in OED: *To appropriate (private property) to the sovereign or the public treasury by way of penalty.* Two more (obsolete) definitions also specifically say *forfeit to the **sovereign or state***. Only their fourth and final definition says ***loosely.** To seize as if by authority; to take forcible possession of, to appropriate summarily.* with no mention of the state.

Comment: <a href="http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=confiscate&searchmode=none"> confiscate</a> : the word is constructed around the Latin root fiscus meaning basket or public treasury

Comment: @FumbleFingers : 'How does the OED decide in what order to list its senses?

It is a historical dictionary, which means that the entries are listed in the order in which they are found to have occurred chronologically.' ( http://public.oed.com/resources/for-students-and-teachers/a-level/ ). // but: 'The dictionary content in ODO focuses on current English and includes modern meanings and uses of words. Where words have more than one meaning, the most important and common meanings in modern English are given first, and less common and more specialist or technical uses are listed below.'

Comment: @user49727 : But the original Greek version of 'sycophant' meant 'a tale-teller about figs'. I've not come across many instances where it was meant to carry this meaning for a year or two now. And ODO has **confiscate** verb
[with object]
take or seize (someone’s property) with authority... >> and 'ODO focuses on current English and includes modern meanings and uses of words. Where words have more than one meaning, the **most important and common** meanings in modern English are given first' (bolding mine. We should concentrate on the most important and common (and easily understood) meanings.

Comment: Regardless of the origin, if you were to say "The police officer confiscated the money", I think most people would assume that the police office was acting within his official duty and that the seller had done something wrong, like not having a permit.  If the police officer was not acting within his official duties, and was taking the money for himself, then extortion, shakedown, or one of the other suggestions would be more appropriate.

Comment: "Confiscation" implies that the act was justified; "extortion" implies that it was not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, When the teacher seizes the comic does he convert it to his own use? If not, I'd say _confiscate_ still applies.

Answer (score 32):

Previously-suggested  *[extortion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extortion#Noun)* (“The practice of extorting money or other property by the use of force or threats”) is quite appropriate; also consider verb  *[shake down](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shake_down)* (“To get money from someone using threats”).

*Edit:* As noted in a comment, as a noun *[shakedown](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shakedown)* means  “an act or instance of shaking someone down; especially : extortion”.  Some other terms related to a policeman  forcibly taking money from a salesman might include:
• *[graft](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graft#Noun)*, “Illicit profit by corrupt means, especially in public life”, “A cut of the take”, “A [bribe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bribe#Noun), especially on an ongoing basis”
• *[squeeze](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squeeze#Verb)* (mentioned earlier by Daniël), “To oppress with hardships, burdens, or taxes; to harass”
• *[put the arm on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+the+arm+on)*, “*Fig.* to apply pressure to someone. [eg] John has been putting the arm on Bill to get him to cooperate.”
• *[muscling in](http://www.yourdictionary.com/muscle)*, “[using] power or influence, esp. when based on force or threats of force”
• *[on the take](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/on-the-take)*, “trying to profit in a personal and usually financial way from a situation”, which might apply if the policeman knows of infractions but is turning a blind eye for a split of the stand's profits.

Note, cambridge.org has thesaurus pages for specific topics, including *[Cheating & tricking](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/topics/honesty-and-dishonesty/cheating-and-tricking/)* which may be relevant.

Comment: m-w's shake-down: 3: an act or instance of shaking someone down; especially : extortion

Answer (score 15):

Colloquially it is also referred to as a *shakedown* or *squeeze*.

In a clear case of *corruption* or a *racketing* it can also be called a *pay off* or *protection money*.

Comment: Nothin' shakin' on shakedown street!

Answer (score 6):

[***confiscate***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confiscate) : To use one's authority to lay claim to and separate a possession from its holder.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where the event took place.

In some jurisdictions, the policeman may well have been acting within the law of the land if the salesman had no licence, and the term **confiscation** would be correct (Collins being superior to the 'stricter' AHD here, of course).

**Robbery** is the alternative, for the taking of money / possessions illegally by force.

Answer (score 2):

*Extortion under color of law / color of official right*

[2404 Hobbs Act — Under Color of Official Right](http://www.justice.gov/usao/eousa/foia_reading_room/usam/title9/crm02404.htm)

> While the definition of extortion under the Hobbs Act with regard to force, violence or fear requires the obtaining of property from another with his consent induced by these means, the under color of official right provision does not require that the public official take steps to induce the extortionate payment: It can be said that "the coercive element is provided by the public office itself."

Comment: Please explain your answer. See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems pretty self explanatory, but it's a regional manner of stating the previously suggested extortion.

Comment: I don't understand "under color of". Do you mean "under *cover* of"? If it's regional, please explain - which region(s)?

Comment: @TrevorD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_(law) it's a legal term in the US.

Comment: @Random832 Thanks. I'd never heard of it (in the UK).

Comment: EL&L isn't my usual stomping grounds, but I gave the regions where applicable and it's the more correct term for North America rather than just plain "extortion."

Answer (score 2):

At first read, I thought "appropriate" would be appropriate:

`The policeman appropriated the salesman's money.`

> ap·pro·pri·ate
>   /əˈprōprē-it/
>   Adjective
>   Suitable or proper in the circumstances.
>   **Verb**
>   **Take (something) for one's own use, typically without the owner's permission.**
>   Synonyms
>   adjective.      proper - suitable - fit - fitting - apposite - convenient
>   verb.   assign - allocate

*[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=appropriate&oq=appropriate&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0j5j0j69i62l2.2355j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*

Comment: I was also thinking of 'appropriate'. I think that it is connotatively a little more neutral than 'extort', though, and is often even used when the action is sanctioned by the narrator, as in 'I appropriated Fido from an abusive neighbour and he turned out to be a faithful companion'.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the circumstances, seize would be my first thought. Usually it is part of a search and seizure.

Another alternative would be impound, but that generally refers to vehicles. The definition is broader than common usage, though.

Comment: I woud question whether "seize" necessarily implies "forcefully" as requested by OP. Seizure (in this context) would be forceful only if there were resistance.

Comment: @TrevorD seize  
Verb
Take hold of suddenly and forcibly: "she jumped up and seized his arm".
Capture (a place) using force.
Moderation is healthy in moderation ;)

Answer (score -1):

If the policeman did not simply grab the money but rather force the salesman to hand it over:

> [blackmail](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blackmail?s=ts): to extort money from (a person) by the use of threats.